# Define a hash with keys of class string without using hash rockets?

Tags: ruby, hash

A hash (with key of class String) can be defined using hash rocket syntax like so:

```rb
h = {:name => 'Charles', "name" => 'John'}
```

Is there a way to define it using another notation?

I tried:

```rb
a = {name: "Charles", "name": "John"}
(irb):14: warning: key :name is duplicated and overwritten on line 14
a
# => {:name=>"John"}
```

Also note that without any overriding, I still can't spot a way to get the key to be class String:

```rb
b = {"name": "John"}
b
# => {:name=>"John"} # "name" (String) is stored as :name (Symbol)
```

AFAIK it's not possible to define a hash with any String keys using the more modern hash notation (the notation that doesn't use the hash rockets). Is there any way, or should the `=>` has rockets be used when defining a hash with a key of class String?

Comment: @Chris weird. When I do `h = {name: "something"}`, then `h.keys` returns `[:name]`, where `h.keys[0].class # => Symbol`

Comment: @Chris: That makes no sense. `{name: "something"}` is the hash literal syntax for `Symbol` keys. Using this syntax, a key *cannot possibly be* anything other than a `Symbol`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/Hash.html) really makes this pretty clear:

> The older syntax for Hash data uses the “hash rocket,” =>:

```
h = {:foo => 0, :bar => 1, :baz => 2} h # => {:foo=>0, :bar=>1,
> :baz=>2}
```

> Alternatively, **but only for a Hash key that's a Symbol**, you can use a
> newer JSON-style syntax...